# Is there a way to sort index from Uppercases to lowercases

Tags: indexing, sorting, xindy

I'm using `xindy` to create indeces. However, the default sort order is not sensible for uppercase and lowercase. Is there a way to create a .xdy file so that the uppercases are sorted in front of lowercases.

Here is an example:

```
A
Abel.......
Alex.......
aboutism...
account....
axis.......

B
Bible......
basics.....
bigger.....
```

I think the issue is, by default, uppercase letters are mapped to lowercase letters, thus cannot be distinguished former and sorted according to that. I wonder if anyone can help me create a .xdy that sorts alphabet **case-sensitively.**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OpTeX then you needn't any external program for sorting index. The sorting is done using TeX macros. There are macros `\_sortingdataLANG` etc. they enables to configure the sorting process.

I copied the default `\_sortingdatalatin` from the OpTeX macros and modified it slightly in order to realize your request. The result is here:

```
\def \sortingdataAa {%
  /,{ },-,&,@,%
  A,a,À,à,Â,â,Ä,ä,Á,á,%
  Ą,ą,%
  B,b,%
  C,c,%
  Ć,ć,Č,č,%
  D,d,Ď,ď,%
  E,e,È,è,É,é,Ë,ë,Ê,ê,Ě,ě,%
  Ę,ę,%
  F,f,%
  G,g,%
  H,h,%
  ^^T^^U^^V,% ch Ch CH
  I,i,Í,í,Ï,ï,Î,î,%
  J,j,%
  K,k,%
  L,l,Ĺ,ĺ,Ľ,ľ,%
  Ł,ł,%
  M,m,%
  N,n,Ň,ň,%
  Ń,ń,Ñ,ñ,%
  O,o,Ö,ö,Ó,ó,Ô,ô,%
  P,p,%
  Q,q,%
  R,r,Ŕ,ŕ,%
  Ř,ř,%
  S,s,ß,%
  Ś,ś,Š,š,%
  T,t,Ť,ť,%
  U,u,Ù,ù,Û,û,Ü,ü,Ú,ú,Ů,ů,Ű,ű,%
  V,v,%
  W,w,%
  X,x,%
  Y,y,Ý,ý,Ÿ,ÿ,%
  Z,z,%
  Ž,ž,%
  Ź,ź,%
  Ż,ż,%
  ^^Z,% Hungarian: cz:c^^Z, etc., see \_compoundcharshu in lang-data.opm
  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'%
}
\let\_sortingdataen = \sortingdataAa % English language will use the \sortingdataAa

\ii Alex
\ii aboutism
\ii axis
\ii Abel
\ii basics
\ii account
\ii bigger
\ii Bible

\nonum\sec Index

\makeindex

\bye
```

See OpTeX manual, sections 1.5.2 and 2.33 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use at own risk.

```latex
% make sure Aa.xdy and Aa_utf8.xdy are in working directory
% pdflatex foo.tex
% xindy -M Aa.xdy foo.idx
% pdflatex foo.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index{Abel}
\index{Alex}
\index{aboutism}
\index{account}
\index{axis}

\index{Bible}
\index{basics}
\index{bigger}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

file `Aa.xdy`:

```
;;; -*- mode: lisp; coding: utf-8; -*-
;;; provided by user691586, May 17 2023
;; USE AT OWN RISK -- THIS IS PROVIDED WITH NO WARRANTY
;; OF ANY KIND NOR LIABILITY OF ANY THING AT ALL
;; (forever)
;; USAGE: put this file together with companion Aa_utf8.xdy
;; in your working directory.  Execute *latex on foo.tex,
;; then xindy -M Aa.xdy foo.idx, then again *latex.

;; (but xindy is hyperref-incompatible last time I checked,
;;  although I don't recall what was this incompatibility,
;;  perhaps something having to do with page hyperlinking)
(require "latex-loc-fmts.xdy")

(require "numeric-sort.xdy")

;; do not use texindy
;; do not load latex.xdy, we copy here what's needed

;(require "latex.xdy")

;; from latex.xdy and tex.xdy

;;;
;;; TeX conventions
;;;

;; Discard leading and trailing white space. Collapse multiple white
;; space characters to blank.

(merge-rule "^ +" "" :eregexp)
(merge-rule " +$" "" :eregexp)
(merge-rule "  +" " " :eregexp)

;; Handle TeX markup

(merge-rule "\\([{}$%&#])" "\1" :eregexp)

;; Standard location classes: arabic and roman numbers, and alphabets.

(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers"))
(define-location-class "roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-lowercase"))
(define-location-class "Roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-uppercase"))
(define-location-class "alpha-page-numbers"  ("alpha"))
(define-location-class "Alpha-page-numbers"  ("ALPHA"))

;;;
;;; Output Markup
;;;

(markup-index :open
"\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }
"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-letter-group-list :sep "~n~n  \indexspace~n")
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n  % ")

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)

(markup-locclass-list :open ", " :sep ", ")
(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")

(require "makeindex.xdy")

(require "latin-lettergroups.xdy")

;; (utf8 *may* work but will require LaTeX from recent
;;  years so that the (in)famous IeC macro is not used
;;  in idx file
;; )
(require "Aa_utf8.xdy")
```

File `Aa_utf8.xdy`:

```
;; -*- mode: lisp; coding: utf-8-unix; -*-
;; Modeled on xindy/lang/general/utf8.xdy and utf8-lang.xdy
;; provided by user691586, May 17 2023
;; USE AT OWN RISK -- THIS IS PROVIDED WITH NO WARRANTY
;; OF ANY KIND NOR LIABILITY OF ANY THING AT ALL
;; (forever)
;; (utf8 *may* work but will require LaTeX from recent
;;  years so that the (in)famous IeC macro is not used
;;  in idx file
;; )
;; USAGE: put this file together with companion Aa.xdy
;; in your working directory.  Execute *latex on foo.tex,
;; then xindy -M Aa.xdy foo.idx, then again *latex.

(define-letter-group "A"           )
(define-letter-group "a" :after "A")
(define-letter-group "B" :after "a")
(define-letter-group "b" :after "B")
(define-letter-group "C" :after "b")
(define-letter-group "c" :after "C")
(define-letter-group "D" :after "c")
(define-letter-group "d" :after "D")
(define-letter-group "E" :after "d")
(define-letter-group "e" :after "E")
(define-letter-group "F" :after "e")
(define-letter-group "f" :after "F")
(define-letter-group "G" :after "f")
(define-letter-group "g" :after "G")
(define-letter-group "H" :after "g")
(define-letter-group "h" :after "H")
(define-letter-group "I" :after "h")
(define-letter-group "i" :after "I")
(define-letter-group "J" :after "i")
(define-letter-group "j" :after "J")
(define-letter-group "K" :after "j")
(define-letter-group "k" :after "K")
(define-letter-group "L" :after "k")
(define-letter-group "l" :after "L")
(define-letter-group "M" :after "l")
(define-letter-group "m" :after "M")
(define-letter-group "N" :after "m")
(define-letter-group "n" :after "N")
(define-letter-group "O" :after "n")
(define-letter-group "o" :after "O")
(define-letter-group "P" :after "o")
(define-letter-group "p" :after "P")
(define-letter-group "Q" :after "p")
(define-letter-group "q" :after "Q")
(define-letter-group "R" :after "q")
(define-letter-group "r" :after "R")
(define-letter-group "S" :after "r")
(define-letter-group "s" :after "S")
(define-letter-group "T" :after "s")
(define-letter-group "t" :after "T")
(define-letter-group "U" :after "t")
(define-letter-group "u" :after "U")
(define-letter-group "V" :after "u")
(define-letter-group "v" :after "V")
(define-letter-group "W" :after "v")
(define-letter-group "w" :after "W")
(define-letter-group "X" :after "w")
(define-letter-group "x" :after "X")
(define-letter-group "Y" :after "x")
(define-letter-group "y" :after "Y")
(define-letter-group "Z" :after "y")
(define-letter-group "z" :after "Z")

(define-rule-set "user-alphabetize"

  :rules  (("Ă" "A" :string)
           ("Ā" "A" :string)
           ("ā" "a" :string)
           ("ă" "a" :string)
           ("Ē" "E" :string)
           ("ē" "e" :string)
           ("Ĕ" "E" :string)
           ("ĕ" "e" :string)
           ("Ī" "I" :string)
           ("ī" "i" :string)
           ("Ĭ" "I" :string)
           ("ĭ" "i" :string)
           ("Ō" "O" :string)
           ("ō" "o" :string)
           ("Ŏ" "O" :string)
           ("ŏ" "o" :string)
           ("ß" "SS" :string)
           ("Ū" "U" :string)
           ("ū" "u" :string)
           ("Ŭ" "U" :string)
           ("ŭ" "u" :string)
           ))


(define-rule-set "user-resolve-case"

  :rules  (("Ā" "8" :string)
           ("ā" "9" :string)
           ("Ă" "8" :string)
           ("ă" "9" :string)
           ("Ē" "8" :string)
           ("ē" "9" :string)
           ("Ĕ" "8" :string)
           ("ĕ" "9" :string)
           ("Ī" "8" :string)
           ("ī" "9" :string)
           ("Ĭ" "8" :string)
           ("ĭ" "9" :string)
           ("Ō" "8" :string)
           ("ō" "9" :string)
           ("Ŏ" "8" :string)
           ("ŏ" "9" :string)
           ("Ū" "8" :string)
           ("ū" "9" :string)
           ("Ŭ" "8" :string)
           ("ŭ" "9" :string)
           ("ß" "99" :string)
           ("A" "8" :string)
           ("B" "8" :string)
           ("C" "8" :string)
           ("D" "8" :string)
           ("E" "8" :string)
           ("F" "8" :string)
           ("G" "8" :string)
           ("H" "8" :string)
           ("I" "8" :string)
           ("J" "8" :string)
           ("K" "8" :string)
           ("L" "8" :string)
           ("M" "8" :string)
           ("N" "8" :string)
           ("O" "8" :string)
           ("P" "8" :string)
           ("Q" "8" :string)
           ("R" "8" :string)
           ("S" "8" :string)
           ("T" "8" :string)
           ("U" "8" :string)
           ("V" "8" :string)
           ("W" "8" :string)
           ("X" "8" :string)
           ("Y" "8" :string)
           ("Z" "8" :string)
           ("a" "9" :string)
           ("b" "9" :string)
           ("c" "9" :string)
           ("d" "9" :string)
           ("e" "9" :string)
           ("f" "9" :string)
           ("g" "9" :string)
           ("h" "9" :string)
           ("i" "9" :string)
           ("j" "9" :string)
           ("k" "9" :string)
           ("l" "9" :string)
           ("m" "9" :string)
           ("n" "9" :string)
           ("o" "9" :string)
           ("p" "9" :string)
           ("q" "9" :string)
           ("r" "9" :string)
           ("s" "9" :string)
           ("t" "9" :string)
           ("u" "9" :string)
           ("v" "9" :string)
           ("w" "9" :string)
           ("x" "9" :string)
           ("y" "9" :string)
           ("z" "9" :string)
           ))


; somewhat random as user691586 does not quite understand
; what is going on
; look in xindy/modules/lang/general/uft8.xdy for more complex
; setup
(define-sort-rule-orientations (forward backward))
(use-rule-set :run 0
          :rule-set ("user-alphabetize"))
(use-rule-set :run 1
          :rule-set ("user-resolve-case"))
```

This has not been tested beyond the above ascii example:

[image]

Comment: when I said it may work with utf8 I was only thinking of Latin based European languages of course as one sees from the code I provided

Answer (score 1):

Xindy puts index entries into dedicated lettergroups by the entry prefix, which is the same as the first letter by default. So it's pretty much sufficient to create lettergroups that account for both upper- and lowercase letters. For example, `case.xdy`:

```
(define-letter-group "A" :prefixes ("A" "a"))
(define-letter-group "B" :prefixes ("B" "b"))
(define-letter-group "C" :prefixes ("C" "c"))
(define-letter-group "D" :prefixes ("D" "d"))
(define-letter-group "E" :prefixes ("E" "e"))
(define-letter-group "F" :prefixes ("F" "f"))
(define-letter-group "G" :prefixes ("G" "g"))
(define-letter-group "H" :prefixes ("H" "h"))
(define-letter-group "I" :prefixes ("I" "i"))
(define-letter-group "J" :prefixes ("J" "j"))
(define-letter-group "K" :prefixes ("K" "k"))
(define-letter-group "L" :prefixes ("L" "l"))
(define-letter-group "M" :prefixes ("M" "m"))
(define-letter-group "N" :prefixes ("N" "n"))
(define-letter-group "O" :prefixes ("O" "o"))
(define-letter-group "P" :prefixes ("P" "p"))
(define-letter-group "Q" :prefixes ("Q" "q"))
(define-letter-group "R" :prefixes ("R" "r"))
(define-letter-group "S" :prefixes ("S" "s"))
(define-letter-group "T" :prefixes ("T" "t"))
(define-letter-group "U" :prefixes ("U" "u"))
(define-letter-group "V" :prefixes ("V" "v"))
(define-letter-group "W" :prefixes ("W" "w"))
(define-letter-group "X" :prefixes ("X" "x"))
(define-letter-group "Y" :prefixes ("Y" "y"))
(define-letter-group "Z" :prefixes ("Z" "z"))

(define-rule-set "ignore-special"
  :rules (("?" "") ("." "") ("-" "") ("'" "") ("!" "") ("{" "") ("}" "")
          ))

(define-sort-rule-orientations (forward))
(use-rule-set :run 0
          :rule-set ("ignore-special"))
```

(`ignore-special` conveniently drops some non-alphabetic characters to ease sorting.)

An example of the indexed TeX source `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,hyphens]{article}

\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Abel\index{Abel}
Alex\index{Alex}
aboutism\index{aboutism}
account\index{account}
axis\index{axis}
Bible\index{Bible}
basics\index{basics}
bigger\index{bigger}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Executing

```
pdflatex test.tex
xindy -M case.xdy test.idx
pdflatex test.tex
```

yields the following result (the second page):

[image]

Note that here we use the fact that Latin letters are naturally sorted by there Unicode (or ASCII) codepoints. If you need to sort more complicated characters, you'd have to extend the `case.xdy` file.